# "(190) Invalid OAuth access token signature" with FacebookWebContext HasPermission

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I just upgrated from the old facebook sdk to the new Facebook C# SDK 5.0.25 (RTW).  I'm doing a simple login to my site with some exteded permissions such as email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access.

Everything works fine until I check for a permission: if (fbWebContext.HasPermission("email"))...  When I do that I get : Facebook.FacebookOAuthException: (190) Invalid OAuth access token signature.

Are you facing that problem?
The following is the code that I'm using:

**JS:**

```
    FB.login(function (response) {
        if (response.session) {
            if (response.perms) {
                // user is logged in and granted some permissions.
                // perms is a comma separated list of granted permissions
            } else {
                // user is logged in, but did not grant any permissions
            }
            window.location.reload();
        } else {
            // user is not logged in
        }
    }, { perms: 'email,read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access' });
```

**C#:**

```
        var fbWebContext = FacebookWebContext.Current;

        if (fbWebContext.IsAuthorized())
        {
            var permissions = new FacebookWebAuthorizer(fbWebContext).Permissions;
            if (fbWebContext.HasPermission("email")) ...
```

Is there something wrong with this approach?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use a different approach:

I don't declare a new variable for the FacebookWebContext.
I don't check is IsAuthorized (to me it gave some problems inside an App).

So, if I were you I would simply try the following, which includes also an authorize request in case the user has not previously given the permissions. Hope this helps.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Facebook.Web;

namespace FacebookCsharpDemo
{
    public partial class askPerm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (FacebookWebContext.Current.HasPermission("email"))
            {
                //permissions given
                processEmail();
            }
            else
            {
                var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer { Permissions = new[] { "user_about_me", "email" } };

                if (auth.Authorize())
                {
                    processEmail();
                }
                else
                {
                    //show permissions error message - not really - facebook c# sdk will redirect the user to the cancelUrlPath defined in the web.config...
                    litEmail.Text = "You must authorize the Application, please try again";
                }

            }

        }

        private void processEmail()
        {
            var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
            dynamic me = fb.Get("me");

            litEmail.Text = me.email;
        }

    }
}
```

In the .aspx page just put a literal called litEmail.

Comment: Thank for your answer. Althought the HasPermission method is throwing the exception.  I think the problem is the access_tolken that I receive.  It doesn't have the dot at the end and it's smaller that the one that I soupose have to get.  Seems like thre's an exchange that I have't performed.    
What version are u using?   
How are you getting the acces_tolken?  
Thanks again.

Comment: Hi, I just edited the sample, so you can create a new page and just copy/paste my code in your web app and test it. Hopefully you are using .net 4, else you have to adapt the "dynamic me =..."... I don't need o get the access token, the C# SDK does the job for me. If I don't have the required permissions, the access token will be null. You can debug and put in a watch: FacebookWebContext.Current.AccessToken I use version 5.0.25 Facebook.dll: "net40-client", FacebookWeb.dll: "Facebook.Web.dll"

Comment: very odd that the HasPermission method throws an exception. It should simply return true or false. Are you sure you are using a good syntax? HasPermission can check only ONE permission. HasPermissions accepts more...